# How to set up Okta Signin Widget in Vue Okta app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, okta, vue-cli-4, okta-signin-widget

I am attempting to integrate the okta signin widget into a Vue 3 project, based on the following: (Okta Sign-In Widget and Vue | Okta Developer). However, it appears that OktaSignIn is not available to import into the config files even after installing via `yarn add @okta/okta-signin-widget`. In other words, I cannot add `import OktaSignIn from '@okta/okta-signin-widget'` to the main.ts, as the package does not appear to be available. Is this widget not yet available for Vue 3 or Vue CLI 4 ?

Example:

```
import OktaSignIn from '@okta/okta-signin-widget'
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js'

const oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
  baseUrl: 'https://${yourOktaDomain}',
  clientId: '${clientId}',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/login/callback',
  authParams: {
    pkce: true,
    issuer: 'https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default',
    display: 'page',
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
  }
});

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
  issuer: 'https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default',
  clientId: '${clientId}',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/login/callback',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
})

export { oktaAuth, oktaSignIn };
```

Comment: When you say `it appears that OktaSignIn is not available` , you're talking about your IDE ?

Comment: Yes, meaning after okta-signin-widget is installed in my vueCLI project, it is visible as a dependency in package.json. However, when I attempt to import it into the main.ts file ex. ```import OktaSignIn from '@okta/okta-signin-widget'```, the widget package does not appear as an available package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "the package does not appear to be available", I assume you're referring to this TypeScript error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module `'@okta/okta-signin-widget'`. `'/projectRoot/node_modules/@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/js/okta-sign-in.entry.js'` implicitly has an `'any'` type.
>
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/okta__okta-signin-widget` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@okta/okta-signin-widget';`

That module does not yet support its own typings, but [there's an open PR for it](https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget/pull/1443). As a workaround, you can declare the typings in your project at `src/okta-signin-widget.d.ts`, based on the PR's [changes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/okta/okta-signin-widget/1431a01ef90074914930e870601ff56fbd91aa12/index.d.ts):

```js
declare module '@okta/okta-signin-widget' {
  export default class OktaSignIn implements OktaSignIn {
    constructor(configuration: OktaSignInConfig)

    renderEl(configuration: { el: string }): void
    remove(): void

    session: {
      get: (callback: (repsonse: any) => void) => void
    }
  }

  export type OktaSignInConfigAuthParamsResponseMode = 'okta_post_message' | 'fragment' | 'query' | 'form_post'

  export interface OktaSignInConfigAuthParams {
    pkce?: boolean
    responseMode?: OktaSignInConfigAuthParamsResponseMode
    issuer?: string
    display?: 'page'
    scopes?: string[]
    responseType?: string[]
  }

  interface OktaSignInConfigi18n {
    en?: {
      'primaryauth.username.placeholder'?: string
      'primaryauth.username.tooltip'?: string
      'primaryauth.title'?: string
      'error.username.required'?: string
      'error.password.required'?: string
    }
  }

  interface OktaSignInConfig {
    baseUrl: string
    logo?: string
    clientId?: string
    redirectUri?: string
    authParams: OktaSignInConfigAuthParams
    i18n?: OktaSignInConfigi18n
  }
}
```